# Putting future professor position on CV

Tags: funding, cv

I have already received and signed an offer letter for a position as an assistant professor. This position will start next fall, to give me time to finish my post-doc. I'll be applying for a number of grants over the next year. Should I include my future position on my CV for these applications? It seems like relevant context for reviewers to have, but I've never seen anyone do it.

Comment: Where will you be applying from and where will the work be done?

Comment: I attended a presentation at the Huntington Library given by Christina O'Connell, who was restoring the famous painting "The Blue Boy". She's restored many paintings over the years, and I joked "But this one will go on your resume, right?" She smiled and said "It's *already* on my resume."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically grants are administered by institutions, and therefore the grant is really to the university and not the individual. Therefore, it is likely that you will be applying for funds on behalf of your new, rather than current, affiliation.

In that case, it certainly makes sense and is more or less *necessary* to include that new institution.

From the [perspective of NIH, for example, they say explicitly](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/how-to-apply-application-guide/forms-e/general/g.240-r&r-seniorkey-person-profile-(expanded)-form.htm#Instructions):

> For individuals who are not currently located at the applicant organization, include the expected position at the applicant organization and the expected start date.

referring to the "biosketch" document which for NIH grants serves the purpose of a formatted CV. And also:

> If your proposed career development award will be at a different site than your current institution, the proposed sponsoring institution will be the applicant organization. You must affiliate your Commons account with that institution so that you have access to records submitted on your behalf.

(this is referring to the class of NIH grants that would most likely be applied for by someone transitioning from a post doc to asst. professor position)

I would suggest looking for similar instructions for whatever organizations you are applying for funding from. You also likely should be working with grant support people at your new institution.

Comment: Exactly. The grant-support office at your _new_ place will care, but/and the corresponding office at your old/current place will _not_ care.

Comment: When the Grant Funding Agency contacts the future institution they will have your start date confirmed - they are likely to check a future date...

Comment: *"Typically grants are administered by institutions"* --- I don't think that is true. Possibly it is true in the US and some other countries.

Comment: @Dilworth For what it's worth, it's true in the UK, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Conveniently, I am in the US, so this is very helpful. Thanks!